# Saving the oucomes of a model run to use as starting point for future runs

Tags: netlogo

OBJECTIVE: My plan is to run my model for ~60 ticks, and use the outcome of that run (i.e. the changes to the patches) as the starting point for all future runs. The idea behind this is that the first 60 ticks simulate a landscape from the past up until today (without any policy interventions). Then, from today on, I want to explore a range of policy scenarios, all starting with the same base conditions.

QUESTION: Do you know if there is a smart way to take stock of / save the outcomes of a run so that I can use them as a starting point for future runs, or do I need to assess the conditions after 60 ticks manually and then build an alternative setup-button that replicates those conditions?

Comment: Have you looked at the export-world and import-world primitives?  The former can export the state of your model after 60 ticks and then your different scenarios can all import the same world at the beginning of their runs.

Comment: Please comply with the expected behavior as clearly laid out in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior):"***Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.***". See also the (provocatively titled) Meta post [No Thanks, Damn It!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Charles that export-world and import-world should work.
An alternative (see code below ) would be to use a fixed random seed for your alternative setup for the first 60 ticks, then change to a run-specific random seed, which would also work on a web-based run.  ( I suspect export-world doesn't work over the web. )

Here's an example of changing the random seed mid-flight.  Be sure to save the random seed before you define the new random seed or everything will always be the same!
Load this code and hit setup and go buttons multiple times and you can confirm it's working.

```
globals [ variable-random-seed   fixed-ticks]
to setup
  clear-all
  set variable-random-seed random 999999999  ;; nine nines works
  random-seed 123456789 ;;  any fixed number to use for low ticks
  set fixed-ticks 10     ;;  or 60 in your case
  print " ----------- fixed ------------- ===== -------- varies by run ----------- "
  reset-ticks
end
to go
  if ticks > 20 [ print "\n" stop ]
  write random 100
  if  ticks = fixed-ticks  [ write "=====" random-seed variable-random-seed ]
  tick
end
 
 Sample output of three runs
```

> ----------- fixed ------------- ===== -------- varies by run
>
> ---

66 68 42 59 14 1 34 20 3 15 86 "=====" 1 80 87 54 85 51 37 53 94 69

> ----------- fixed ------------- ===== -------- varies by run
>
> ---

66 68 42 59 14 1 34 20 3 15 86 "=====" 94 72 60 26 18 90 65 50 65 18

> ----------- fixed ------------- ===== -------- varies by run
>
> ---

66 68 42 59 14 1 34 20 3 15 86 "=====" 23 93 75 68 17 44 17 30 99 94

Comment: Nice solution Wade.